# how can i upload image to parse server Back4app using Ktor?

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

i am trying to upload image to parse server

but it return

`https://parsefiles.back4app.com/ehUKQVObBspFk0MBFNSSg3MwLJofpeoFtDhQNIgS/2f345485e2e5cc757c80cfdacf138871_hello.png`

whitch contains image cant be displayed because it contain error

it success on uploading image but image is corrupted

note : when i use same code to upload pdf or mp3 files it works well

```
val response = client.post<HttpResponse>("https://encyriptionapp.b4a.io/parse/files/hello.png") {
        headers.append("X-Parse-Application-Id", PublicData.Application_Id)
        headers.append("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", PublicData.REST_API_Key)
        body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                append("file", file/*bytes*/, Headers.build {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                })
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Is it reproducible with another HTTP client, like Postman or Insomnia?

Comment: It is working perfectly with postman  , i send image as binary data

Comment: Could you please share the code for receiving a response body?

Comment: can you please check this Repo  'https://github.com/ashrafdawoud/EncryptionAppKmm'      CommonMain -> DataSource -> Network -> KtorInterfaces -> UploudFilesCalls

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem. I get `IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.BFCAI.encryptionapp.android.BaseAplication` error while running an android application in an emulator. Could you please describe how do you use `encyriptionapp.b4a.io` service?